# What is the most appropriate control panel for virtual hosting behind Nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, cpanel, controlpanel, server

I have several domains on Digital Ocean hosting which runs behind Nginx server. I am using it mainly for python aps, but I would like to setup them with PHP as well.

Python apps run behind Gevent middleware. Now I need a control panel to make some upgrades via GUI such as :

```
- mail server installation and management 
- web stats installation and management 
- Wordpress/Magento installation and management
```

Please help me to chose control panel which is convenient for installation behind already running Nginx server. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is something which will fulfill your expectation, and I'm pretty certain.
But closest to your needs seems to be Ajenti / Ajenti V control panel.